# switch/hide div JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I expand a division it can't be collapse again. All I need is when the division is shown I want to hide it again when clicking on it.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="login_area" id="clickHere2">
    Signup

    <div class="drop-down" id="signup_area_hover">
        Signup
    </div>
</div>

<div class="login_area" id="clickHere">
    Login

    <div class="drop-down" id="login_area_hover">
        Login
    </div>
</div>

<div class="drop-down" id="dropdown_login">
    <div class="dropdown_login_header">
        <div class="beeper_value"></div>

        <div class="beeper_login"></div>
    </div>Hello World 111
</div>

<div class="drop-down" id="dropdown_signup">
    <div class="dropdown_signup_header">
        <div class="beeper_signup"></div>
    </div>Hello World 2222
</div>
```

and here's the JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $( '#clickHere' ).click(function() {
     $( '#dropdown_login' ).slideToggle(500);
});

 $( '#clickHere2' ).click(function() {
     $( '#dropdown_signup' ).slideToggle(500);
});     

</script>
```

I want to add an if condition if the clickHere is shown, ClickHere2 hides and vice versa.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: possible duplicate of [switch and hide div on click JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112855/switch-and-hide-div-on-click-jquery)

Comment: i've tried the toggle , but toggle ain't helping cuz toggle is taking no effect , i dunno where's the wrong part in my JS code

Comment: Why are you posting same question twice? If you want to update the question, you need to edit and update the content?

Comment: @Siva Charan , as u can see i stopped receiving answers over there and stil my problem ain't solved ???

Comment: To be honest, I really don't understand your question. Can you be more detailed? "When my page opens, I see THIS, When I click on this div, I want X to happen" "When I click on this other div, I want Y to happen", etc.

Comment: might be an issue with importing jquery javascript file.

Comment: try your coding fresh html file only the given div and javascripts code, and try some debugging like console.log or atleast by alert statement.try to figure out where is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the toggle / slideToggle functions in jquery.
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ and https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/
There are examples on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R2UfU/)

**jQuery:**

```
$( "#myBtn" ).click(function() {
     $( "#myDiv" ).toggle();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Toggle</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
#myDiv {
    background-color:red;
    height:75px;
    width:75px;
}
```

**Resources:**

- http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: martynas ... i know this , the problem is im switching between two divisions

Comment: @HossamDin I think your question could be answered faster if you posted a jsFiddle :)

Comment: i tried but the JSfiddle ain't launching it which kinda weird !! but wait i will send it to you